# Flutter dynamic lists

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart, listview

I'm missing something about dynamic lists.
I have a list, where for each item it should create another list of radio buttons and all should be independent from one another.

For more context. Think of this as a quiz like application, where there is a list of questions and each question has a list of answers. My question is how can I select one answer for each question using radio buttons.

I have data which comes in this format

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "question": "",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "questionid": 7,
                    "answerid": 3,
                    "answer": "Over 55 years",
                    "points": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my widget tree

```
class SliverBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SliverBodyState createState() => _SliverBodyState();
}
class _SliverBodyState extends State<SliverBody> {
  Future? getQnA;
  int totalPoints = 0;
  StepperType _stepperType = StepperType.vertical;
  int _currentStep = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    String token = context.read<AuthProvider>().token;
    getQnA = context.read<ApiProvider>().getQnA(token);
    super.initState();
  }
  _stepperView(QuestionsResponse resp) {
    tapped(int step) {
      setState(() => _currentStep = step);
    }
    continued() {
      // ignore: unnecessary_statements
      _currentStep < resp.data!.length - 1
          ? setState(() => _currentStep += 1)
          : print('Action\nPoints\t$totalPoints');
    }
    cancel() {
      // ignore: unnecessary_statements
      _currentStep >= 1 ? setState(() => _currentStep -= 1) : null;
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200.0),
      child: Stepper(
        type: _stepperType,
        currentStep: _currentStep,
        onStepTapped: (step) => tapped(step),
        onStepContinue: continued,
        onStepCancel: cancel,
        steps: resp.data!
            .map((e) => Step(
                  isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
                  state: _currentStep >= resp.data!.length - 1
                      ? StepState.complete
                      : StepState.disabled,
                  title: Text(
                    e.question!,
                    style: kLabelStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                  content: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: e.answers!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Answer ans = e.answers![index];
                      int? selectedValue;
                      _handleRadioValueChange(int? value) {
                        selectedValue = value;
                        print(
                          'Question \t${ans.questionid}\nAnswer \t$selectedValue',
                        );
                      }
                      return RadioListTile<int>(
                        value: ans.answerid!,
                        title: Text(ans.answer!),
                        groupValue: selectedValue,
                        onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
  _body() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getQnA,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Center(
                child: GlobalInfoDialog(message: 'Internal Server Error'),
              );
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: GlobalInfoDialog(message: 'Internal Server Error'),
                );
              } else {
                QuestionsResponse resp = snapshot.data;
                return _stepperView(resp);
              }
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return GlobalLoaderContained();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SliverFixedExtentList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([_body()]),
      itemExtent: size.height,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how can I select one answer for each question using radio buttons.